# Will implementation implement what it's interface extends?

Tags: java, interface, implementation, extends

It's a very basic thing but the point is that I don't know it. My question is that will a class **implicitly** implement an interface, which is extended by the interface implemented by the class, **explicitly**. For example:

```
interface Foo extends Bar {
}

class FooImpl implements Foo {
}
```

Now, will `FooImpl` be implementing `Bar` automatically ?

Comment: Yes. That's what `extends` means.

Comment: Quick! Thanks for that

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Now, will `FooImpl` be implementing `Bar` automatically ?

Not *automatically*, you need to provide the implementation (unless `Bar` consists entirely of default methods), but yes, from a type perspective, `FooImpl` *is a* `Bar` because `Foo` *is a* `Bar`, and `FooImpl` *is a* `Foo`.

Comment: Compiler force him to implement them anyway :)

Comment: @sᴜʀᴇsʜᴀᴛᴛᴀ: Well, yes, again provided it's not purely a set of default methods. But I figured it was useful to call it out.

Comment: In short, if `Foo` extends `Serializable`, then `FooImpl` is also `Serializable` ?